# Write a plugin/form for SQL server enterprise manager

Tags: sql-server, plugins, ssms

Is it possible to write a plugin or a form for SQL Server Enterprise Manager version 8? I'm doing some simple queries all the time to admin the databases. So wondering if I could write something for it.

Comment: I suppose those queries can't be molded into a view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the old SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager?? I don't think that old clunker had any extensibility points, sorry....

SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2005 and newer) is based on Visual Studio and thus does have some extensibility - but it appears to be somewhat of a black art to write such a plugin - very little information is available.

Some is here:

- [The Black Art of Writing a SQL Server Management Studio Add-In](http://jcooney.net/post/2007/11/26/The-Black-Art-of-Writing-a-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2005-Add-In.aspx)
- [Building a SQL Server Management Studio Add-In](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/15/building-a-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx)
- [Extend Functionality in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio with Add-ins](http://aspalliance.com/1374_Extend_Functionality_in_SQL_Server_2005_Management_Studio_with_Addins.all)
- [SSMS Scripter - Internals, part 2 - plugging in](http://markegilbert.wordpress.com/2006/12/18/ssms-scripter-internals-part-2-of-3-%E2%80%9Cplugging-in%E2%80%9D/)

Comment: Precisely that old clunker. I like that one, its simple fast and not too flashy. I just wish all DB interfaces were like that. Besides, I don't think upgrading to a new one is going to happen any time soon in my place. But thank you very much for the links, I suppose that when we upgrade, I'll look into your postings again.

Answer (score 1):

Since I usually do all my work in a query window, I just use a bunch of custom written stored procedures that I made, passing in parameters as necessary.  all of my redundant work is done this way.